Ivy: Multiple artifacts with same name at retrieving
I am going to replace some libs in a project by Ivy dependency management.
In my ivy.xml I have the following dependency:
<dependency org="org.apache.myfaces.core" name="myfaces-impl" rev="2.0.25"/>

If I run the ant build right now (with the next dependency as simple jar in the lib folder) it succeds.
Now I add the next dependency:
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-test" rev="3.0.5.RELEASE"/>

If I start the build again, I get the following warnings:
[ivy:retrieve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:retrieve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:retrieve]      merged artifact not found: org.testng#testng;6.8.21!testng.jar. It was required in org.apache.myfaces.core#myfaces-impl;2.0.25 -> org.testng#testng;5.1
[ivy:retrieve]      merged artifact not found: org.testng#testng;6.8.21!testng.jar. It was required in org.springframework#spring-test;3.0.5.RELEASE -> org.testng#testng;5.10

Afterwards the build fails with
impossible to ivy retrieve: java.lang.RuntimeException: problem during retrieve of application: java.lang.RuntimeException: Multiple artifacts of the module org.testng#testng;6.8.21 are retrieved to the same file! Update the retrieve pattern  to fix this error.

I don't think the retrieve pattern is the part, where I have to change something, because it seems that there is something wrong at the merge. But this is my retrieve pattern:
<ivy:retrieve pattern="${dirs.lib.ivy}/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" />

What am I doing wrong?
